# Metadata file could not be found when publishing asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a project targeting .NET Core 2.1 that has a reference to a project targeting .NET Standard 2.0.

Everything compiles and runs fine, but when I try to publish, it fails with this error:

Metadata file 'C:\projects\asp.net\Project Name\Project Name.BusinessLogic\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\Project Name.BusinessLogic.dll' could not be found

It appears to be looking for a nonexistent \netcoreapp2.1\ directory instead of \netstandard2.0\ where the dll actually is.

I think it might be using the referencing project's target rather than the referenced project's target to construct the path, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I would take a look in your .csproj file and see if there is anything that stands out in there. Maybe it's referencing the dll directly rather than the project, or maybe a HintPath is in there throwing it off (I've had that one a couple times)

Comment: Thanks but no, it's a ProjectReference and there are no HintPaths

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug ([#9690](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9690)) in v2.1 that may get fixed in v2.2.1

The workaround is to remove the TargetFramework tag from the Properties\PublishProfiles\<profile>.pubxml file